# How to prevent Sublime Text from remembering last open folders

Tags: sublimetext3

A recent sublime text dev update (subl3) introduced a feature where the sidebar remembers what folders were open on exit. They also stay open when parent folder closes.

I'd like to disable this, because it's very annoying.

I see only this - the closest to it, but there's nothing like this for sidebar.

```
"remember_open_files": true,
"remember_full_screen": false,
```

What option values to set to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 "hot_exit": false,
 "remember_open_files": false,
```